# how to arrange the elements in a database according to one column in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, sorting

```
$op= array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  
 $op[]=$row;
 }
 rsort($op['clicks']);  //this line is not working
 print_r($op);
```

how to sort all the rows according to one particular column in **php**.
Here the sorting done according to the number of **clicks**.And also in **descending** order.

Comment: Why not actually do it via an ORDER BY clause in your SQL query; that would be far more efficient

Comment: Otherwise; it would be `usort($op, function ($a, $b) { return $a['clicks'] < $b['clicks']; });` because you're not sorting a simple array, your'e sorting a 2-dimensional array

Comment: THANKS .GREAT HELP MARK BAKER!!

Comment: Is that really far more efficient?